# How to keep your old migration as reference?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

- I have **38** migration script that I wrote in Laravel 4.

[image]

- I **don't** want to throw them away, but I also **don't** want to run them either. I just want to keep them as references.
- If I place them in the migration folder in Laravel, it will run when I do

`php artisan migrate` and that will break some part of my database, as they have already been run.

- I'm wondering if there is a way to mark them as already run, so Laravel will not trying to run them again.
- I notice the `migration table` in my database - can I do something with it ?

What is the best way I should do to those 38 migrations ? Feel free to give me any suggestions.

Comment: If you just want to keep them as reference, why not just make a directory e.g. `app/database/old-migrations` and move them there?

Comment: Does Laravel write to the database itself to keep track of what migrations have been run? Propel ORM writes to a table to do so - aha, I guess that would be what the `migration` table is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing -- Laravel will only run each migration once.  It keeps track of which migrations have run in the `migrations` table.  The whole idea of migrations is a series of date sortable scripts that you can run at anytime start to finish and they rebuild your database, AND that you can add to without needing to rerun them all as they work (so your data is preserved)

If you're running

```
php artisan migrate
```

and Laravel's running a migration it has already run, something is very broken with your system.

(Speculation follows) It seems more likely the **latest** migration you're running may have halted half way though in a place MySQL couldn't rollback the changes, and Laravel's trying to rerun the latest one.  Try a

```
php artisan migrate:rollback
```

Fix the error in the breaking migration, and you'll be all set.